# Extension Modules disappeared

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I don't have any error logs or other info that I can figure out what's the issue, is not the first time that it happens. In my case is when I installed an extension, basically I do what is recommended after uploading the extension, clean cache and login again on admin, and everything is ok when I installed, the only problem is that sometimes the module disappeares has nothing was installed, and only shows again if a go and "clean Cache" on the admin panel.

Comment: you may want to try taking this to [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/) as more people there will have relevant knowledge, though it is slower than StackOverflow.

Comment: It surely is hard to resolve such an issue without logs or error messages.

Comment: I have a idea what could be, but im not sure if this is the cause, since im using redis im not sure if this could influence extension/modules.

Comment: @Info E: `Does somebody have the same issues?` I think, your question could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple web-nodes, separate admin nodes then it can be possible that the new codes might have not deployed to one of your servers and the old xmls are cached.

And I understand that you are using redis as your caching layer, so sometimes flushing the cache from magento admin panel doesnt flush the entire redis cache.

So you would need to try to connect to the redis server using redis-cli command then issue 'flushall' there.